# Fill diagonals of matrix according to vector

Tags: matlab, matrix

I'd like to transform a vector

```
v = [1,2,3,4]
```

into a matrix (4x4) with diagonals like this:

```
 1  2   3  4
 2  1   2  3
 3  2   1  2    
 4  3   2  1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to generate a [**Toeplitz matrix**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toeplitz_matrix), so you should use the [**`toeplitz`**](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/toeplitz.html) function.

```
v = [ 1 2 3 4 ];
out = toeplitz(v)
```

---

```
out =

     1     2     3     4
     2     1     2     3
     3     2     1     2
     4     3     2     1
```

Answer (score 0):

If A is your 4x4 array, just do:

```
A(1:5:end) = 1:4;
```

Best

Comment: the answers not corrcet

Answer (score 0):

```
v = [1 2 3 4];

A = gallery('circul',v);    
B = triu(A,0)+triu(A,1)';
```